# Deleting polymorphic objects and memory leaks

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose I have a class A and a class B which inherits from A.
Then I do something like:

```
A* a = new B();
delete a;
```

Why a memory leak happens only when there is a dynamic memory allocation within B?
How C++ knows to remove the "B part" when there is dynamic memory allocations within B but fails where it is?

[Update:]

How does the following code does not result in a memory leak: [I suspect it to be undefined behaviour, but I don't really understand anything :(]

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class A {
public:
    virtual void f() {
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout<< "A A'tor" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
private:

public:
    B(){}
    ~B(){
        cout<< "B D'tor" << endl;
    }
    void f() {
        cout << "2" << endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    A* a = new B();
    //a->f();
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `A` has a virtual destructor, both `A` and `B`'s destructors will get called.

Comment: This isn't clear.  There's only a memory leak if you forgot to declare the destructor `virtual`, or forgot a corresponding `delete` in the destructor(s) itself.  A proper code sample would help clarify your situation.

Comment: It's pretty unclear, what you're asking about now.

Comment: If `A` does not have a virtual dtor, deleting a derived class using a pointer to `A` is undefined behavior. If it does have one, the most derived dtor is called, which will properly deconstruct the object. If it does not, you need to debug your dtors.

Comment: I have edited my question and hope it is clear what I'm asking now.

Comment: If you want to delete an object of derived type, through a pointer to its base class, the base class must have a virtual destructor.

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you write `unique_ptr<A> p = make_unique<B>();` instead, because then you don't need to write (and worry about forgetting) the `delete` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

While compiler sees statement "delete a;"
It knows only static type of "a" is pointer to A, if there is no virtual destructor in class A. As a result wrong destructor gets called leading to memory leak

If there is a virtual destructor in class A
then compiler comes to know that Dynamic type of "a" is pointer to B and there will a vtable from where it will get B's destructor address at run time

Comment: I know that even when a destructor for both classes defined explicitly there is still a memory leak when B has dynamic memory managment. So your explanation does not work.

Comment: virtual ~A() // try this

Comment: I know that virtual destructor fixes this. but I'm interested in understanding the case I explaned.

Comment: @Doppelganger: How does that case differ?  You don't have a virtual destructor, so you invoke UB.

Comment: If there is a virtual destructor in class A, statement A* a = new B(); creates an object of Class B, whose first 4 byte is the address of vtable of class B. "delete a;" statement knows address of exact vtable

Answer (score 0):

This is because the destructor isn't virtual. If there is ever a chance in your program to delete derived class objects via base class pointers, you should define a virtual destructor in the base class. This will allow B's destructor to get called first, allowing you to free any dynamic memory B may have allocated. A's destructor will get called after B's.

Another good rule of thumb is to train yourself to think about making your destructor virtual **anytime** you make a method virtual. Since the motivation to make a method virtual means you will be calling methods on base class pointers, it follows that you will likely be deleting objects through base class pointers.